# Update a table using summed values from another table in MySQL/mariaDB

Tags: mysql, update, group-by, sum

I was trying to use the query below to update the `ORDERS` table by making the `O_TOTALPRICE` column up-to-date when the `LINEITEM` table is modified. And I was using a standard TPC-H database.

```
UPDATE ORDERS O, LINEITEM L
  SET
    O.O_TOTALPRICE = SUM(L.L_EXTENDEDPRICE * (1 - L.L_DISCOUNT/100) * (1 + L.L_TAX/100))
  WHERE
    L.L_ORDERKEY = O.O_ORDERKEY;
```

However, this results in `1111 - Invalid use of group function`.

---

The operation is like this:

```
-----------------LINEITEM----------------       ---------ORDERS---------
L_ORDERKEY  L_EXTPRICE  L_DISCOUNT  L_TAX       O_ORDERKEY  O_TOTALPRICE
==========  ==========  ==========  =====       ==========  ============
1           12.99       20          8.5     ┬   1           <TO CALC>
1           8.99        30          11      ┘
2           99.99       10          10      ┬   2           <TO CALC>
2           49.99       0           8.5     ┤
2           3.99        50          14.7    ┘
```

---

Since there are multiple rows in `LINEITEM` corresponding to the record in `ORDERS`, I tried to add `GROUP BY L.L_ORDERKEY`, but that just came to a syntax error.

Is this possible to accomplish in the `UPDATE` statement, or does it have to be split to multiple statements? Thanks!!

Comment: Note how redundant the `L_` is, since it is preceded by `L.`.

Comment: For syntax error, please show the entire statement, and the "... near '..." of the error message.  It always points at the bad spot.

Comment: I recommend you update the question to include the desired results, ie, what should `ORDERS` look like after a successful update

Comment: @RickJames The `L_` is in the TPC-H DDL file, and I didn't change it. I do agree the `L.` is so extra, though.

Comment: @RickJames The whole `1111` error message is shown in the question, I wonder why mariaDB didn't tell me which line had the error. In fact, I was using this `UPDATE` statement in a stored procedure, and the creation is fine,. But when executing the procedure, I get the `1111` error with no indication which part is wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `L.L_EXTENDEDPRICE` should be `L.L_EXTPRICE`
- `L_DISCOUNT` and `L_TAX` are percentages, in which case the values stored in `LINEITEM` need to first be divided by 100.0 before performing calculations

Some sample data:

```
drop table if exists LINEITEM;
drop table if exists ORDERS;

create table ORDERS
(O_ORDERKEY      int
,O_TOTALPRICE    decimal(10,2));

insert into ORDERS values
(1,0.0),
(2,0.0);

create table LINEITEM
(L_ORDERKEY      int
,L_EXTPRICE      decimal(10,2)
,L_DISCOUNT      decimal(10,2)
,L_TAX           decimal(10,2));

insert into LINEITEM values
(1,12.99,20, 8.5),
(1, 8.99,30,11),
(2,99.99,10,10),
(2,49.99, 0, 8.5),
(2, 3.99,50,14.7);
```

Contents of `ORDERS` **before** the update:

```
select * from ORDERS;

O_ORDERKEY  O_TOTALPRICE
----------  ------------
         1          0.00
         2          0.00
```

Proposed update statement:

```
update ORDERS O
set    O.O_TOTALPRICE  = (select sum(L.L_EXTPRICE * (1 - L.L_DISCOUNT/100.0) * (1 + L.L_TAX/100.0))
                         from   LINEITEM L
                         where  L.L_ORDERKEY = O.O_ORDERKEY);
```

Contents of `ORDERS` **after** the update:

```
select * from ORDERS;

O_ORDERKEY  O_TOTALPRICE
----------  ------------
         1         18.26
         2        155.52
```

Here's a [rextester fiddle](http://rextester.com/GLTEL81978) of the above.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when making the boxed chart. But hopefully it does not affect the main part of the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: not sure I understand your comment; if you've made a typo in the question then I'd suggest you update the question otherwise ... have you tried the proposed update and if so, what happened ... error? wrong answer? correct answer?

Comment: I am sorry for the trouble! I am outside now (using the app on my phone), and I will try the proposed answers once I am back to my computer.

Comment: Yes, this does work! I am very sorry it took me so long to get back to this, and I had you wait for the follow-up this long!

Comment: no problem, glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE  ORDERS
    JOIN  
        ( SELECT  L_ORDERKEY,
                  SUM(L.L_EXTENDEDPRICE * (1 - L_DISCOUNT) * (1 + L_TAX)) AS ep
            FROM  LINEITEM 
            GROUP BY L_ORDERKEY
        ) AS j  ON j.L_ORDERKEY = ORDERS.O_ORDERKEY
    SET ORDERS.O_TOTALPRICE = j.ep;
```

If that fails, try this syntax:

```
UPDATE  ORDERS
    SET O_TOTALPRICE = 
        ( SELECT  SUM(L.L_EXTENDEDPRICE * (1 - L_DISCOUNT) * (1 + L_TAX))
            FROM  LINEITEM
            WHERE  L_ORDERKEY = ORDERS.O_ORDERKEY 
        )
```

Comment: Will join operation take more time?

Comment: The `JOIN` will probably be faster, since it is computing all the  new values at once.   The subquery with the `SUM` is probably slower.

Comment: @jackxujh: compare query plans and execution metrics to know for sure which is slower/faster (assuming there is in fact a difference); a lot will depend on how the query engine decides to parse/compile the query

Comment: Both the `ORDERS` and `LINETIEM` tables actually have many more columns, and foreign keys. And `ORDERS` is referenced by `LINEITEM`. ( also a TPC-H thing) But the `O_TOTALPRICE` is not not referenced nor a prime key. Considering all these, will the `JOIN` still faster?

Comment: @markp - The query plan won't show the whole picture.  Table size and bulkiness of the columns play a factor.

Comment: @jackxujh - try both.  You are better able to say which is faster.

Comment: @RickJames Does the number of rows whose `O_TOTALPRICE` are really changed after the update affect the time needed for the `UPDATE` query?